# Flutter Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context

Tags: flutter, setstate

I keep getting this error when trying to post data and the solutions say to check `if(mounted)` before calling `setState` but I don't know where this `setState` is? The code is below; the function is in the first widget and then I call it in another widget:

```
// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mne/Forms/form_model.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../Network/api.dart';

class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FormWidget> createState() => FormWidgetState();
}

class FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {
  // to show error message

  _showScaffold(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(message, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 20),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          label: 'Press to go back',
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent));
  }

  final List<FormModel> _formfields = [];
  var loading = false;
  var isEmpty = false;
  List activityResponses = [];
  late Map<String, List<dynamic>> data;

// to fetch form fields
  fetchFormFields() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var saved = localStorage.getString('activitytask_id');

    var res = await Network().getData('mobile/activity-fields/$saved');

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(res.body);
      final tdata = data['data'];
      if (tdata.length == 0) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('error');
      }

      var formfieldsJson = tdata;

      setState(() {
        for (Map formfieldJson in formfieldsJson) {
          _formfields.add(FormModel.fromJson(formfieldJson));
        }
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _numberController2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchFormFields();
  }

  submitResult() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? responseData = localStorage.getString('responses');
    final String responseList = json.decode(responseData!);
    final List responseList2 = [responseList];

    debugPrint(responseList.toString());
    data = {"activity_responses": responseList2};
    var res = await Network().authData(data, 'mobile/activity-result');

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('activitytasks');
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('error');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    _numberController2.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  // to display form fields
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: loading
                ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _formfields.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      final nDataList = _formfields[i];

                      return Form(
                          child: Column(children: [
                        Column(children: [
                          if (nDataList.type == 'text')
                            Column(children: [
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 6),
                                child: Text('Add a ${nDataList.name}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    controller: _textController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        contentPadding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                        labelText: nDataList.name),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                              Colors.green)),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    var responseData = {
                                      "activity_field_id": nDataList.id,
                                      "value": _textController.text
                                    };
                                    activityResponses.add(responseData);
                                    debugPrint(activityResponses.toString());
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Save',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                          if (nDataList.type == 'number')
                            Column(children: [
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: 5, left: 6, top: 5),
                                child: Text('Add a ${nDataList.name}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    controller: _numberController2,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        contentPadding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                        labelText: nDataList.name),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                              Colors.green)),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    // valueResponses.add(_numberController2.text);
                                    // idResponses.add(nDataList.id);
                                    var numberData = {
                                      "activity_field_id": nDataList.id,
                                      "value": _numberController2.text
                                    };
                                    activityResponses.add(numberData);
                                    debugPrint(activityResponses.toString());

                                    SharedPreferences localStorage =
                                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                                    final String encodedData =
                                        (activityResponses).asMap().toString();
                                    final String encodedData2 =
                                        jsonEncode(encodedData);
                                    localStorage.setString(
                                        'responses', encodedData2);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Save',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                        ]),
                      ]));
                    })));
  }
}
```

The above code is the first widget where I have written `submitResult()` . The code below is for the page containing the button that will call `submitResult()` :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../Design/custom_shape.dart';
import 'form_widget.dart';

class Workspace extends StatefulWidget {
  const Workspace({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Workspace> createState() => WorkspaceState();
}

class WorkspaceState extends State<Workspace> {


  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 246, 219),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
                ClipPath(
                    clipper: CustomShape(),
                    child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 128),
                        height: 335,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/fields.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth))),
                Container(
                  height: 650,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 140,
                  right: 8,
                  height: 600,
                  child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      width: 360,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              height: 450,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: const FormWidget()),
                          if (isLoading)
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                            Colors.green)),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = false;
                                  });
                                  await FormWidgetState().submitResult();
                                  if (!mounted) return;
                                  setState(() {
                                    isLoading = true;
                                  });
                                  // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: const Text('Submit',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              ),
                            )
                          else
                            const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1)))
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ])),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you

Edit: Adding this image after removing the

```
// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously
```

to show where the error is. [image: screen snip to show the error]

Comment: Remove the `// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously`  at the top of the first file. The IDE will then tell you where exactly is this BuildContext gap.

Comment: I took it out but I am still getting this error in the framework.dart:             
   BuildContext get context {
    assert(() {
      if (_element == null) {
        throw FlutterError(
          'This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct). \n'
          'Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.',
        );
      }
      return true;
    }());
    return _element!;
  }
  StatefulElement? _element;

Comment: When you take out the line, the IDE is suppose to highlight somewhere in the files that have the errors. But if it doesn't, no problem. Now this error you are getting (widget has been unmounted), try to locate on which line of which Dart file is the error happening. Look at the error logs. Each log line usually ends in a dart file name and line number. Locate the line of the files that were defined by you. That way we can identify where exactly is the Asynchronous BuildContext taking place.

Comment: I took a screen snip and added it to show the line. It says the error is on the                   if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('activitytasks');
    } else {
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('error'); 
    }
  }

Comment: Great, I've seen the issue, let me type an answer.

Comment: But wait, why do you have this `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` statements in the code? I thought its mainly used in main method at the start of the Flutter launching, not necessarily when the app is running already.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. I will remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above code is the first widget where I have written submitResult() . The code below is for the page containing the button that will call submitResult()

Something is wrong. You should not call a method of a [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) object by simply initialising that `State` object and calling its method inside a different widget altogether as you did somewhere in the second snippet:

```dart
await FormWidgetState().submitResult();
```

`State` objects are tied to widgets. Flutter continuously discards and recreates widgets but keeps their `State` object. For Flutter to properly manage a `State` object, the tied widget must be part of the widget tree.

The IDE shows the above error because the context of that Navigator is not part of any widget tree. There is no widget linked to the `State` object when submitResult is called.

From the arrangement in the second code snippet, you have a `FormWidget` inside a Column. In that same Colum, you have the if-block that has a button with the problematic `await FormWidgetState().submitResult();` in its onPressed callback.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
        height: 450,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: const FormWidget()),
    if (isLoading)
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            // ...
              onPressed: () async {
                // ...
                await FormWidgetState().submitResult();
                if (!mounted) return;
                // ...
              },
            child: const Text('Submit',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        )
    else
      const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 161, 39, 1)))
  ],
),
```

If my guess is right, you want to display the FormWidget and have the submit button to call `submitResult()` from that FormWidget. And that's why you did `await FormWidgetState().submitResult();` in the onPressed callback.

Well, the `await FormWidgetState().submitResult();` line is not tied to a widget, it is separate. It has no parent per se and it is not part of the widget tree. So, this explains why you get the above error. The `FormWidget` in the Container above the if-block is very different from the State widget you reinitialized in the problematic `await FormWidgetState().submitResult();` line. When rendering the UI, Flutter had auto-initialized and linked a hidden FormWidgetState object for the above FormWidget.

In fact, `if (!mounted) return;` really has no effect the way we think it should. Because its own containing widget will always mounted inside that method. But then the preceding problematic line's `mounted` getter has nothing to do with this one's own. (Hope you understand).

##### Solution

The solution is to merge the upper and lower part of the Column into one widget. So that submitResult call would share the same context as the displayed widget (or rather will have a valid context).

You have 2 options:

1. Move this entire column to inside FormWidget
2. Move the definition submitResult out of FormWidget and into the second code snippet's file. Then call submitResult when the FormWidget's form is filled. You will have to find a way to save data externally (maybe using state management or shared preferences) across both widgets.

I expanded the details/steps of Option 1 as follows:

1. Let `FormWidget` take the isLoading bool parameter. The parent (second code snippet) will give it its value: `FormWidget(isLoading)`.
2. Move the Column of the second code snippet to inside the build method of the first. `FormWidgetState`'s build method should return that column. Your good programming skills will guide you on this step as it is a little technical. The upper part of the Column should be the ListView.builder. The Column should of course be inside the Scaffold's body.
3. The Column's lower part (the if-else block) should use widget.isLoading as bool condition. Remember that this isLoading came from the parent (step 1).

---

Noticed some other issue with the first code snippet.

Look at the definition of `fetchFormFields()` method that is called in `initState()`. You see, that method seems to have a possibility of an error too. You have an if block that does Navigation but does not add a return statement. So if navigation was successfully, the following setState call might be an error (as the FormWidget is no longer mounted).

The comments in the following code will explain. I added the return statement:

```dart
fetchFormFields() async {
  setState(() {
    loading = true;
  });

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var saved = localStorage.getString('activitytask_id');
  var res = await Network().getData('mobile/activity-fields/$saved');

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    final tdata = data['data'];
    if (tdata.length == 0) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('error');

      // maybe a return statement is supposed to be found here. 
      // adding return statement here prevents the next setState from being called
      return;
    }

    var formfieldsJson = tdata;

    // because if tdata.length was actually zero, the Navigator would have 
    // navigated out and this widget will no longer be mounted.
    // 
    // setState here would then be called on a "no-longer-existing" widget.
    //
    // But the added return statement in the if block above should prevent this.
    setState(() {
      for (Map formfieldJson in formfieldsJson) {
        _formfields.add(FormModel.fromJson(formfieldJson));
      }
      loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This has been helpful and it has worked well. I added the return; as well as put the container with the SubmitResult button inside the form, under the last save button. thank you